# SharePoint 2013 Distributed Cache Service to store session state

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

We are developing a solution based on SharePoint 2013 Foundation. There is a new Distributed Cache service available in SharePoint 2013. When we checked the web.config for a new sample SharePoint web application, we found it was configured to use "In-proc" mode for storing session-state. Can we leverage this distributed cache service to store session state?

Also I saw powershell cmdlets for configuring session state in database in the following msdn article : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee890113.aspx. Is database a preferred way to store session state rather than Distributed Cache for SharePoint 2013?

Are there any other alternatives also available to store session state in SharePoint 2013?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will have to use the SharePoint Session State Service by using the `Enable-SPSessionStateService` PowerShell cmdlet from the article you linked to.

The SharePoint Distributed Cache Service is meant for Cacheable items, especially the Feed, Login Tokens and App Tokens. I did not see an implementation for a Session State Provider. There is a nice explanation about the distributed cache service here:

- [Distributed Cache Service in SharePoint 2013](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d2ee01/distributed-cache-service-in-sharepoint-2013/)

The service depends on Azure or more specifically on the AppFabric caching infrastructure. You can implement your own stuff to access this Caching framework as explained here:

- [Caching In WCF Services: Part 2 - AppFabric Distributed Cache](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/caching-wcf-services-part-2)

As said previously, SharePoint uses the Session State Service, which in turns uses standard ASP.NET session state:

- [Using Session State in SharePoint 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markarend/archive/2010/05/27/using-session-state-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

As you said correctly the default mode for the state service is set to `In-Proc` (in memory). What you would normally do is set it to `SQLServer` so the Session state is saved to some database and can be retrieved by multiple servers. The PowerShell cmdlets you linked in your post do that automatically for you.

So in short: By implementing your own ASP.NET Session State Handler you could circumvent the normal SharePoint State service and leverage the Distributed Cache, however that won't be easy and maybe it is easier to just use a State database.

Comment: Thanks @moontear for quick reply. There is an msdn article which provides information on using AppFabric Cache as ASP.NET session state   provider (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790859(v=azure.10).aspx). Can I do similar change in a SharePoint web application configuration file and hence use AppFabric Cache as session provider? Is there any other specific change which will have to do to make it work for SharePoint? I want to avoid SQL Server since AppFabric would give better performance for session state.

Comment: Nice find. Yes you do any web.config modification you can normally do. Of course it wouldn't be the Microsoft way - so basically you will have to try.